# How to determine the Calculate Range by the Value in a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert a button in excel and by clicking it I can recalculate a certain area ( The area is not determined, it depends on how many rows I pasted in the sheet.)

I want to recalculate column N to V, From row 2 to the last row

in the cell `X2` I will type in the row number.
I hope I can pass this value to macro then determine the range

However, `Range("N2:LastCell").Calculate` is wrong.

```
Sub Calculate_selected()
Sheets("GPS Data").Select

Dim rownumber As Integer
Dim LastCell As String
rownumber = Range("X2").Value
LastCell = "V" & rownumber


Range("N2:LastCell").Calculate

End Sub
```

by the way, if I type 10 in cell `X2` and use `MsgBox LastCell` , it will show V10.

Any suggestion is appreciated!!!

Comment: `Range("N2:" & LastCell).Calculate`